# Caching with Redis on a Parse Server

Tags: cache, redis, parse-server

I'm on a `2.6.3` Parse Server and I need to cache the results of queries, to speed things up!

I understand that Parse Server offers a Redis adapter. What exactly do I have to do, in order to start using Redis? Are there any modules I should install? Anything I should import or configure?

Also, I found this on Parse's documentation: `Those cache adapters can be cleaned at anytime internally, you should not use them to cache data and you should let parse-server manage their data lifecycle.`

What do they mean by saying `you should not use them to cache data and you should let parse-server manage their data lifecycle.`? Should I not use the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the cache adapter is meant for the exclusive use of Parse Server to cache its own internal data. It means that any code you write should not attempt to use the cache adapter or alter the cache in any way.

Comment: So why is the adapter available, if I can't use it?

Comment: Read the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: Yeah you're saying that Parse Server itself manages the adapter for its own reasons! So, how could I use Redis, if I can't use its adapter?